# Paul Irish, how does he do it?

Tags: javascript, mouse, effects

How does [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/) get that cool effect with the mouse on the sidebar?

Comment: Gotta be a CSS3/HTML5 thing, doesn't work in an older browser.

Comment: Which effect? (15 chars)

Comment: He explains in his very own blog post [My harmonious background canvas](http://paulirish.com/2010/my-harmonious-background-canvas/).

Comment: I think that Paul's script is broken somehow... The harmony examples work fine in my browser, but I don't see any such effect on his page.

Comment: I disabled it for Firefox users because the CPU would spike to 100% and they'd complain. It stays pretty chill in webkit and opera though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He uses HTML5 CANVAS with http://mrdoob.com/120/Harmony in Ribbon Mode.

EDIT: He Forked the code and release his own version for MouseMove. you can download it here. https://github.com/paulirish/harmony

Answer (score 0):

http://paulirish.com/harmony/harmony.js  Here is how.

Yes its a HTML5 functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the Javascript that does that effect:
[Harmony](http://paulirish.com/harmony/harmony.js)

Here's a [link](http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/689) from the webpage.